# How to Array object along curve or mesh correctly?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, curve-modifier

As you can see I was trying to have this wall panel array following the curve and it's doing an okay job but as you can see below its not very good in all the angles...so it ends up deformed.
Is there any better way to do this ? It doesnt have to array to the curve it can array to a mesh too that would work (so i would be sticking my panels to the wall essentially.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please share the blend file so we can take a closer look. You can use: [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/)